# Initialization of a static data member of a C++ template

Tags: c++

I wrote the following function object template class:

```
template
<typename P=double, typename C=double>
class VAT{
public:
    VAT(P p):percentance(p){};
    P operator()(C currency ){
        currency = currency + currency * (percentance/100);
        return currency;
    }
private:
    P percentance;

};
```

which will operate over a standard container and change the values of it, like:

```
std::transform(prices.begin(),prices.end(),prices.begin(),std::bind(VAT<double,double>(25),std::placeholders::_1));
```

what I want to achieve is to have a `sum` that will be update as the prices are changing. So I thought to have a static data member, so I rewrite the template including a `static C sum = 0` and

```
P operator()(C currency ){
        currency = currency + currency * (percentance/100);
            sum = sum + currency;
        return currency;
    }
```

But this is not correct. Is there anyway to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can, with a little tweak to your class and the way you are using it.

```
template <typename P=double, typename C=double>
class VAT{
  public:
    VAT(P p, P& sum):percentance(p), sum(sum) {};
    P operator()(C currency ){
        currency = currency + currency * (percentance/100);
        sum += currency;
        return currency;
    }
  private:
    P percentance;
    p& sum;

};

double sum = 0.0;
VAT<double, double> vat(25, sum);
std::transform(prices.begin(),prices.end(),prices.begin(),vat,std::placeholders::_1));
// Now you can use sum ...
std:cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Comment: I was looking more for a solution without passing a reference to sum or having it as a global variable. This solves the problem but it is a bit ugly solution. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Avraam: Using a `static` variable is much uglier than this. `static` variables have many of the same problems as globals -- lack of thread safety, lack of re-entrancy, lack of explicitness.